# How to achieve High availability in QuickFIX/J 2.1 with ConnectionType=initiator?

Tags: high-availability, failover, quickfix, quickfixj

We are using `QuickFIX/J 2.1` with `ConnectionType=initiator`.

We have configured our `PersistMessages` to `Y` and are saving all the messages to `Oracle Database`.

Now we are trying to make our FIX engine `highly available`.

In the official [documentation](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/acceptor_failover.html) they have mentioned the `acceptor` failover support but no clue on `initiator`

Can some one please guide us on how to achieve HA for `ConnectionType=initiator`.

Comment: Which aspect of your application do you want to make highly available? "Achieve HA" is very unspecific. In general you need to implement this by yourself in your application since this is not built into QuickFIX/J.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn for replying. We want to run 2 instances of QuickFIX/J initiator in active passive mode..any guidance on how to go about it.